# csr_matrixの非ゼロ要素を全て表示・保存する方法

Tags: python, python3

ある行列があり、`scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`クラスで保存されています。行と列を指定した非ゼロ要素のみが保存されている状態です。(例：以下はデータの一部です

```
(0, 8) 1
(0, 14) 1
(0, 258) 1
```

このようなcsr_matrixで表示されている状態のデータが必要なので、保存したいのですがうまくいきません。
素朴な方法として、`numpy`の`set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)`として全要素を`print`、そしてコピーアンドペーストをしようとしたのですが、それもうまくいきません。（全部表示されない）
csr_matrixの中身をすべて`print`する方法、もしくはtxtやcsvファイル形式に保存できる方法はありませんか？

Comment: [scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html) で dense matrix(numpy.ndarray型)に変換すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @metropolis アドバイスありがとうございます。dense matrixに変換すると非ゼロ要素以外も表示されてしまいます。あくまでも必要なのは例のように表示されている形式の非ゼロ要素だけです

Comment: すみません、勘違いをしていました。それでは当該の行列が `csr` だとすると  `csr.maxprint = csr.count_nonzero()` としてから print する方法が考えられます。

Comment: @metropolis その方法で解決しました。ただ、全部表示されているようですが、スクロールできない部分まで表示されていたので、printされている結果をtxtに保存したら欲しかった結果が手に入りました。ありがとうございます。この場合、この質問に解決方法を追加しておくべきですか？

Comment: 他の方法の回答が寄せられるかもしれませんが、ご自身で回答して、それを承認してしまって構わないかと思います。

Comment: @metropolis metropolisさんの回答のおかげなので、貴方にクレジットが付くような方法があればそうしたいのですが、、。とりあえず回答を載せます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
your_csr_matrix.maxprint = your_csr_matrix.count_nonzero()
with open("result.txt","w") as file:
　　　file.write(str(your_csr_matrix)) 
　　　file.close()
```

metropolisさんのコメントで解決したので、回答として残しておきます。

```
your_csr_matrix.maxprint = your_csr_matrix.count_nonzero()
```

で`csr_matrix`の非零要素を全て`print`で表示することができます。